# Solving the following Initial Value Problem: $y'=\frac{x}{1+y^2}$, $y(-1)=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new to this and I'm stuck on one of my problems in the book.  $y'=\frac{x}{1+y^2}$  with $y(-1)=1$.

I know I need to find $P(x)$ and then integrate $e^{\int P(x)}$. I am thinking that my $P(x) = x$ here, so when I integrate I have $e^\frac{x^2}{2}$.

However, I'm lost on what to do after. Can someone guide me through this example and show what to do with the $y(-1)=1$?

Comment: this is a non-linear ODE, so the integrating factor thing does not work. Try separation of variables instead as $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{1+y^2}$

Comment: @dezdichado I knew something was wrong with it, because it doesn't follow the usual method I do. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard exercise in what's called separable ODE. Write $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{1+y^2}\implies \int(1+y^2)dy = \int xdx\implies y+\frac{y^3}{3} = x^2+C.$ This is the general formula for your function and it is an implicit one, so you cannot hope to find a better looking formula unless you want to solve a cubic equation. Now, simply use the initial condition to find what $C$ is.

Answer (score 0):

***Another hint***

$$y'=\frac{x}{1+y^2}$$
$$1+y^2=xx'$$
$$\frac 12 (x^2)'=1+y^2$$
$$\frac 12 x^2=\int 1+y^2dy= \frac {y^3} 3 +y+K$$
$$\frac {x^2}2= \frac {y^3} 3 +y+K$$
$$y(-1)=1 \implies \frac {1}2= \frac {1} 3 +1+K \implies K=- \frac 56$$
$$\boxed {\frac {x^2}2= \frac {y^3} 3 +y-\frac 56}$$